# How to add a header with an image and a textview to my navigation drawer?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have a navigation draw with sections and items, but I need to put an image and a text as header but don't know how exactly from what I have, the navigation drawer that I have is the default one that android studio create when you right click and select new > activity > navigation drawer activity.

this is the xml that I want to have as header:
nav_header.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Character's Avatar -->
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer_header_iv_image"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image_sorcerer"/>

    <!-- Character's name -->
    <TextView android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer_header_tv_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Example text"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The navigation drawer content is set through a custom adapter

GameNavigationFragment class (This is the fragment that manage the navigation drawer)

```
public class GameNavigationFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";

private static final String PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "navigation_drawer_learned";
private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mCallbacks;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerListView;
private View mFragmentContainerView;

private int mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;

public GameNavigationFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Read in the flag indicating whether or not the user has demonstrated awareness of the
    // drawer. See PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER for details.
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    mUserLearnedDrawer = sp.getBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, false);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
        mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
    }

    // Select either the default item (0) or the last selected item.
    selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    // Indicate that this fragment would like to influence the set of actions in the action bar.
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
    mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    });

    CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(getActivity());
    adapter.addSeparatorItem("Menu");
    adapter.addItem("Section 1");
    adapter.addItem("Section 2");
    adapter.addItem("Section 3");
    adapter.addSeparatorItem("Opciones");
    adapter.addItem("Section 1");
    adapter.addItem("Section 2");
    adapter.addItem("Section 3");


    mDrawerListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return mDrawerListView;
}
```

CustomAdapterListView

```
package com.jomasa.pocketfantasy.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import com.jomasa.pocketfantasy.R;

public class CustomListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_SEPARATOR = 1;

    private ArrayList<String> mData = new ArrayList<String>();
    private TreeSet<Integer> sectionHeader = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context){
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public void addItem(final String item) {
        mData.add(item);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void addSeparatorItem(final String item) {
        mData.add(item);
        sectionHeader.add(mData.size() - 1);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return sectionHeader.contains(position) ? TYPE_SEPARATOR : TYPE_ITEM;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return mData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        int rowType = getItemViewType(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            switch (rowType) {
                case TYPE_ITEM:
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.snippet_item1, null);
                    holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
                    break;
                case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.snippet_item2, null);
                    holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textSeparator);
                    break;
            }
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.textView.setText(mData.get(position));

        return convertView;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView textView;
    }
}
```

GameActivity

```
package com.jomasa.pocketfantasy.activities;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;

import com.jomasa.pocketfantasy.R;
import com.jomasa.pocketfantasy.fragments.GameInventoryFragment;
import com.jomasa.pocketfantasy.fragments.GameMainFragment;
import com.jomasa.pocketfantasy.fragments.GameNavigationFragment;
import com.jomasa.pocketfantasy.fragments.GameSheetFragment;

public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements GameNavigationFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

    /**
     * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
     */
    private GameNavigationFragment mGameNavigationFragment;

    /**
     * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
     */
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

        mGameNavigationFragment = (GameNavigationFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();

        // Set up the drawer.
        mGameNavigationFragment.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.container, GameMainFragment.newInstance(position))
                        .commit();
                break;

            case 1:
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.container, GameInventoryFragment.newInstance(position))
                        .commit();
                break;

            case 2:
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.container, GameSheetFragment.newInstance(position))
                        .commit();
                break;

            default: break;
        }
    }

    public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
        switch (number) {
            case 1:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.navigation_title_main);
                break;
            case 2:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.navigation_title_inventory);
                break;
            case 3:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.navigation_title_sheet);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void restoreActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!mGameNavigationFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
            // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
            // decide what to show in the action bar.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_game, menu);
            restoreActionBar();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

this is how navigation looks like right now:
[image]

Comment: use `Material Design's` `Navigation View` example [here](http://www.android4devs.com/2015/06/navigation-view-material-design-support.html)

Comment: I tried that option yesterday and didn't help me, I think I have to add something to my custom adapter but I don't know what it is exactly.

Comment: Update android studio to 1.4 and create Slider activity that comes with material slider with header image and title

Comment: The slider activity is easier?

Comment: create inside `fragment_navigation_drawer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Update your android studio to 1.4 then you can create a navigation drawer activity with header image

Answer (score 0):

This is something I'm working into.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!-- Contenido Principal -->
    <include layout="@layout/main_content"
        android:id="@+id/mainContent"/>

    <!-- Navigation Drawer -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I am currently using Navigation View pattern. See this property in the NavigationView:

```
app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
```

Where you need yo replace drawer_header with your layout file.
If you want to use NavigationView, you have to add this dependency in your Gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

Hope this helps.