# Navigation drawer using text and icon

Tags: java, android, eclipse, icons, navigation-drawer

I want to add icon for each item of the navigation drawer. Currently, The navigation drawer just have a text. Summing up, I want to create a navigation drawer with a text and icon *(text+icon)*. How can i make this ?

**Main_Activity:**

```
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;

import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * This example illustrates a common usage of the DrawerLayout widget
 * in the Android support library.
 * <p/>
 * <p>When a navigation (left) drawer is present, the host activity should detect presses of
 * the action bar's Up affordance as a signal to open and close the navigation drawer. The
 * ActionBarDrawerToggle facilitates this behavior.
 * Items within the drawer should fall into one of two categories:</p>
 * <p/>
 * <ul>
 * <li><strong>View switches</strong>. A view switch follows the same basic policies as
 * list or tab navigation in that a view switch does not create navigation history.
 * This pattern should only be used at the root activity of a task, leaving some form
 * of Up navigation active for activities further down the navigation hierarchy.</li>
 * <li><strong>Selective Up</strong>. The drawer allows the user to choose an alternate
 * parent for Up navigation. This allows a user to jump across an app's navigation
 * hierarchy at will. The application should treat this as it treats Up navigation from
 * a different task, replacing the current task stack using TaskStackBuilder or similar.
 * This is the only form of navigation drawer that should be used outside of the root
 * activity of a task.</li>
 * </ul>
 * <p/>
 * <p>Right side drawers should be used for actions, not navigation. This follows the pattern
 * established by the Action Bar that navigation should be to the left and actions to the right.
 * An action should be an operation performed on the current contents of the window,
 * for example enabling or disabling a data overlay on top of the current content.</p>
 */
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private String[] mPlanetTitles;
    private ImageView mIcon;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
                ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(0);
        }
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }




    /* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_websearch).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }




    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
         // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
         // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action buttons
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_websearch:
            // create intent to perform web search for this planet
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
            intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, getActionBar().getTitle());
            // catch event that there's no activity to handle intent
            if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.app_not_available, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* The click listner for ListView in the navigation drawer */
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {

         Fragment fragment = new PlanetFragment();
         Bundle args = new Bundle();
         FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

        switch(position){   
        case 0:
            // update the main content by replacing fragments
            args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        case 1:
             // Capture the article fragment from the activity layout
            //QuestionActivity articleFrag = (QuestionActivity)
             //       getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.FrameLayout1);
            Fragment newfragment = new QuestionActivity();
            // update the main content by replacing fragments
            args.putInt(QuestionActivity.ARG_POSITION, position);
            newfragment.setArguments(args);
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, newfragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



            //FragmentManager fragmentManager1 = getFragmentManager();
            //Fragment frag1 =(Fragment) fragmentManager1.findFragmentById(R.id.);
            //Bundle args1 = new Bundle();

            //Fragment frag1 =(Fragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.)
             // This method will be executed once the timer is over
            // Start your app main activity
           // Intent i = new Intent(this, QuestionActivity.class);
          //  startActivity(i);
            // close this activity
           Toast.makeText(this, "Indicativo de acao ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break; 

        case 2:
            // update the main content by replacing fragments
            args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break; 

        case 3:
            // update the main content by replacing fragments
            args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break; 

        case 4:
            // update the main content by replacing fragments
            args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        case 5:
            // update the main content by replacing fragments
            args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        case 6:
            // update the main content by replacing fragments
            args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        case 7:
             // This method will be executed once the timer is over
            // Start your app main activity
            Intent j = new Intent(this, ScreenSplash.class);
            startActivity(j);
            // close this activity
            finish();

            Toast.makeText(this, "Indicativo de acao ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;          
            }        
    }




    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }



    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }



    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    /**
     * Fragment that appears in the "content_frame", shows a planet
     */
    public static class PlanetFragment extends Fragment {
        public static final String ARG_PLANET_NUMBER = "planet_number";

        public PlanetFragment() {
            // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_planet, container, false);
            int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PLANET_NUMBER);
            String planet = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array)[i];

            int imageId = getResources().getIdentifier(planet.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()),
                            "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
            ((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageResource(imageId);
            getActivity().setTitle(planet);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

**drawer_list_item: (xml)**

```
<!--
  Copyright 2013 The Android Open Source Project

  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
  -->

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"/>
```

**string (xml):**

```
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>
    <string name="b_salvar">Save</string>

    <string-array name="planets_array">
        <item>Main</item>
        <item>Ask</item>
        <item>Earth</item>
        <item>Mars</item>
        <item>Jupiter</item>
        <item>Saturn</item>
        <item>Uranus</item>
        <item>Neptune</item>
        <item>Fragmento 1</item>
    </string-array>


    <string name="drawer_open">Open navigation drawer</string>
    <string name="drawer_close">Close navigation drawer</string>
    <string name="action_websearch">Web search</string>
    <string name="app_not_available">Sorry, there\'s no web browser available</string>
    <string name="title_activity_question">QuestionActivity</string>

</resources>
```

Comment: Did you consider to use the [Android Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.ch/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html)? There is an easy example with icons and text.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33125513/how-to-add-a-header-with-an-image-and-a-textview-to-my-navigation-drawer/33125923#33125923

Answer (score 0):

You can use navigation view for navigation drawer like the following,

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

 <!-- Your contents -->

 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
     android:id="@+id/navigation"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_gravity="start"
     app:menu="@menu/my_navigation_items" />
```

The navigation_items.xml will looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/inbox"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_inbox_black"
        android:title="@string/inbox_string" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/starred"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_star_black"
        android:title="@string/starred_string" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/sent_mail"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_send_black"
        android:title="@string/sent_mail_string" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/drafts"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_drafts_black"
        android:title="@string/draft_string" />


    <item
        android:id="@+id/allmail"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_email_black"
        android:title="@string/all_mail_string" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/trash"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_delete_black"
        android:title="@string/trash_string" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/spam"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_error_black"
        android:title="@string/spam_string" />

</group>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will find many tutorials here on stackoverflow and actually people will link you to those tutorials, but I guess you are really new to android to are meaning to understand this wonderful new world. Now I started off with the planets example too.

1. You can see a textview only because your drawer_list_item only has a textview, you start by new .xml file to write a template where the list item contains a textview and an imageview.
2. Now you have your view ready. You need data to populate that view. `<string-array name="planets_array">` this array holds data that will be loaded into the textview, similarly you need an array or something similar to hold the names of the image resource files which you will place in your resources folder.
3. Finally you need an adapter to bind the two, that in the case of your example is done by this line

   mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this,
                   R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));

You need a class for your custom adapter and a class for your viewholder, you need to extend an adapter class, for the sake of simplicity just extend the ArrayAdapter class and override the getview() function. Going back to the viewholder, this would define the and view elements in your list ie, a textview and imageview. set the data for the views in the getview function, the data that you defined in your array.

Hope this will help your understand the tutorials better.
Cheers

Comment: Thank you. I saw videos and tutorial about how to add icon at the NavigationDrawer, but they use NavigationView and other methods. You explained well the step-by-step. I will try to do what you said.